# SharePoint Modern Page to Show only Sum Value from List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-pages

I am using SharePoint Modern. Can I display only sum value of selected column from List on Page?
I do not want to show all the List Item. Best is to show as a textbox in Page

Comment: There is no SharePoint out of the box web part to achieve this.

Comment: Any workaround available on this?

Comment: Create simple app using Power Apps to show the count/sum OR develop simple SPFx web part (This will help for longer run as you can make if configurable to select list & list columns from web part properties).

Comment: I am quite new to SharePoint. As far as I can see from my SharePoint, I dont see any access to SPFx or SharePoint Designer, though I am admin of the site. May I ask, How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If the selected column is a number column, you could use OOTB sum function.
[image]

As a workaround, you could open the list in the excel, then calculate in the excel.

Reference:

https://www.spguides.com/open-sharepoint-list-in-excel/

---

Update:

Display column sum in the other page by using scripts.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58890560/sum-of-sharepoint-list-items-in-particular-field
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3ef7d887-9fa3-416c-9350-520bb2b1df4a/camlquery-to-display-calculated-column-total?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am looking for just extract the sum value, so that I can display the value in a label or box form (part of dashboard) in the modern Page.

Comment: Per my knowledge, there's no OOTB way to achieve this.

Comment: Any workaround or alternative ways to achieve? Or maybe some script?

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check.

Comment: Will the script applicable in SharePoint modern page?

Comment: Yes, you should deploy PnP modern script editor web part into SharePoint Online, add PnP modern script editor web part into page, then add codes in it.